# How to count how many times a number appears in a .txt file

Tags: java, io

Good morning,

I'm doing some Java exercises and stumbled upon this question. I have a .txt file with several numbers, one per line. The goal of the exercise is to see which numbers are equal to 10^0, ... , 10^n until reach n. Then, i have to write in a .txt how many times each one of then appears.
So i have a file with:

1
100
100
100
10
1
1

And i need to write:

1 - 10
3 - 1
3 - 100

I can read the file, check then number and print then. I just can't figure how to make a counter than stays correct. Any help?

Here is the piece of code:

```
// TODO - Count how many time a number appears.
public static void numberOfTimes (BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out, int n)        throws IOException {

        String s;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if (i == Math.pow(10, j)) {
                counter++;
                out.write(Integer.toString(counter) + " " + Integer.toString(i) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you have to count only the numbers like 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc? in other words, can you have, say, the number 45 in the source file?

Comment: Yes, the source file has lots of numbers mixed up. I just need to, given a certain n, check all of then, see which ones are 10^0 to 10^n and count those.

Answer (score 5):

Since there are multiple counts to keep track of, a single integer counter is clearly not going to suffice.

One possibility is to use [`Map<Integer,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for the counts. Since this is homework, I leave it to you to figure out the details.

Another possibility is to use an array of counts, and use `log10(i)` as the index into the array. In other words, the count for `10^k` will be stored at the `k`-th position in the array. *Hint:* In your code, you are already indirectly computing `log10(i)`.

Comment: +1 for the log10 idea, which would work in this particular case but not for any number (unlike the map that would instead work always).

Comment: or you can just use the string length - 1 (= number of zeroes)

Comment: Hum, never used or heard of the $Map<Integer,Integer>, but i will take a look at the API.

Comment: I was thinking like this: store all the found values in a array, then look into the array for each one. If found for example 3 10^0, then counter1 = 3, 10^1 counter2 = 2, etc. But this looks very inefficient, and i would like to have a more elegant and short solution. Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with Integer you can preload a `Map<Integer,Integer>` with all the values less than Integer.MAX (2,147,483,647).

The Map will need all values from 10^0,10^1,...,10^9 as the keys (this is ten (10) keys in total) .  What you then do is perform a boolean check on the value you are reading in, if it matches one of these keys increment the value of that key by 1.